# How to insert Dataframe into Google Sheet dynamically using pygsheet

Tags: pygsheets

I am trying to insert a number of Dataframes into google spreadsheet. I am using the pygsheets module.

I have a variable that the stores the row number in a loop. I am trying to have the Dataframe inserted in the corresponding cell reference. I am doing as per below but I see the Dataframe gets overwritten in the same cell as it runs through a loop

```
sheet.set_dataframe(df, 'A' + '1 + x')
```

My expectations are to insert in the below 3 Dataframes starting from cells `A6, A11, A16` respectively. Currently x has a value of `5` and it changes to `10` and `15` respectively as part of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand why you are not substituting for x. anyway this will do what you want in py3

```
sheet.set_dataframe(df, f'A{1+x}')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply this helped. I however am wondering how could I insert 2 empty rows after inserting the values from a Dataframe. I was not able to find any method to insert empty rows, is this something you might be able to help with.. Thanks again..

Comment: you dont need to insert empty rows (assuming they are already empty), just skip then and insert data after two rows. if not empty user clear() to clear specific row

Comment: I tried using `clear()` but it threw an error clear not defined. I am trying to have another Dataframe inserted in a loop and hence trying to have a few empty rows in between

Comment: sheet.set_dataframe(df, f'A{1+x + 5}') this should add 5 rows offset. this is clear https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/worksheet.html#pygsheets.Worksheet.clear . use the range appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:-

```
sheet.set_dataframe(df, ('A' + '1 + x'))
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: thanks for the rely but I am still having the same problem